# Displaying nth row of Pascal's triangle

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program in c++ in which takes the users input and displays that specific row of Pascal's triangle. 
i.e. inputting 3 should result in 1 3 3 1. 
However when I input 3 in my program it displays "1 1 1 1". I think I'm fairly close but I can't quite work out what's wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n, k, fact1, fact2, fact3, number1, number2, number3, nTakeAwayK, nChooseK;

void CalculateNChooseK();

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a row number for Pascal's Triangle: ";
    cin >> n;
    int x = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
    {
        cout << x << '\t';
        CalculateNChooseK();
        x = nChooseK;

    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void CalculateNChooseK()
{
    fact1 = 1;
    for (number1 = 1; number1 <= n; number1++)
    {
        fact1 = (fact1 * number1);
    }

    fact2 = 1;
    for (number2 = 1; number2 <= k; number2++)
    {
        fact2 = (fact2 * number2);
    }

    nTakeAwayK = (n - k);
    fact3 = 1;
    for (number3 = 1; number3 <= nTakeAwayK; number3++)
    {
        fact3 = (fact3 * number3);
    }

    nChooseK = fact1 / (fact2*fact3);
}
```

Comment: what did you find out with the debugger?

Comment: you have to learn to use functions and local variables

Comment: I don't seem to get any errors from the debugger. I was attempting to call the CalculateNChooseK procedure in the for loop so that it would calculate n choose k everytime k incremented.

Comment: This rampant abuse of global variables will only get you into trouble. I'm with pm100 here. You need to scope those to the blocks where they're relevant. Also why are you calling out to the system `PAUSE` command? If you want to wait for a line of input, C++ can do that natively.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of a noob at this, which variables should have been local, the factorials I take it?

Comment: use the debugger to look at various variables, for example are fact1 and fact2 what you expect them to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to this.. Hope this will help

```
for (k = 1; k <= n+1; k++)
{
    cout << x << '\t';
    CalculateNChooseK();
    x = nChooseK;

}
```

As you are declaring k in for loop, This value is not working as global.

```
for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) // don't declare k here.. and also loop from 1 to n+1 inclusive
```